# How to remove logout page

Tags: magento2.2.4, logout

How to remove logout page 5 seconds when logout after?please help
using magento 2.2.4.
thank you!

Comment: explain in detail what you need

Comment: i want to remove XXX.com/customer/account/logoutSuccess/ page. dont want to showing "You have signed out and will go to our homepage in 5 seconds." page. just reurl to home page.please help ,thank you @MurtuzaZabuawala

Answer (score 5):

create preference of  `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout` class

and override `execute` method

in the `execute` method you find below code

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/logoutSuccess');
```

replace above code with below

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('');
```

Create `Preference` add below code in your module's `di.xml`

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Account\Logout"/>
</config>
```

and in your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Account\Logout.php` file
add below code

Comment: how to Redirect to homepage? thank you @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: @rigu , this line `$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');` will redirect to home page

Comment: No, it will redirect to "xxx.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5iZXJpZ3UuY29tL2N1c3RvbWVyL2FjY291bnQvaW5kZXgv/" @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: Is working now^^, but need change to code $resultRedirect->setPath(''); <- need remove */*/ will be redirect to home page @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: @rigu updated as per your suggestion

Comment: @rigu if this answer helps you then mark as accepted so other users can take benifit from this

Comment: There is no need for a "preference" here. All you need is an "afterExecute" plugin and set the redirect path there. Preference, aka class rewrite, means that you take ownership of the class. This is always a last resort.

Comment: It worked for me. Perhaps the complete answer could include how to create a preference so you would not have to look for another topic just to create the preference. It would help beginners in Magento 2.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz give me 15 mins I will add that to

Comment: That worked fine for me, thank you very much. Just so others aren't making the same mistake, make sure to change the namespace at the beginning of Logout.php to [Vendor]\[Module]\Controlller\Account - I made that grave mistake! :)

Comment: As @ShawnAbramson said, this is NOT a recommended approach - this can be accomplished using before/after plugins rather than preferences. Rewriting classes should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create an after plugin. Like @ShawnAbramson and @ThomasHarding already said.

Create a module and in your module a file `[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Customer/Controller/Account/LogoutPlugin.php` file add below code

Use the following code:

```
<?php
/**
*
*/
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;

/**
 * (Logout)Plugin for redirecting to homepage after logout
 */
class LogoutPlugin
{

  /**
   * Redirect to homepage
   * @param Logout $subject
   * @param Redirect $resultRedirect
   * @return Redirect
   */
  public function afterExecute(Logout $subject, Redirect $resultRedirect): Redirect
  {
    $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
    return $resultRedirect; 
  }
}
```

In `[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/di.xml` add the following code:

```
  <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout">
    <plugin
      name="vendor_module_logoutplugin"
      type="[Vendor]\[Modele]\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account\LogoutPlugin"
      sortOrder="1"
    />
  </type>
```

After you have done this replace [Vendor] & [Module] with your own module. And do a setup:di:compile to make it work.